# libgdx viewport segment with orthographic camera

Tags: android, opengl-es, libgdx

Does anybody knows, how to cut out camera viewport to smaller size than screen? e.g if I want to have status bar at the top of the screen and moving camera cut only to the area without this status bar? The problem is that camera viewport is always stretched to full screen.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Generally the way I do this is by defining two cameras. One for the UI and one for the game world. The UI camera never changes it's position only the world camera moves around.

Then when rendering your UI (assuming you are using SpriteBatch) you simply do this:

```
batch.setProjectionMatrix(gameCamera.combined);

// ... render your game code

batch.setProjectionMatrix(uiCamera.combined);

// ... render ui code
```

Just make sure you update your camera as per normal if it has changed via camera.update()